# Copy Database in assets to data/database work in emulator but not work in device

Tags: database, copy, assets

i have this code: Working in emulator but fail in devices. 
i want copy the database stored in assets to data/data/.... when load app apears "Error File" (FileNotFoundException e) -> error

```
public void copiarDB() {
        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/MiBD";
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("datosejer"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error IO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        AdaptadorBD db = new AdaptadorBD(this);
        // ---obtener todos los contactos---
        db.abrir();
        Cursor c = db.obtenerTodosLosDatosEjercicio();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // DisplayContact(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.cerrar();
    }

    public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        // ---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Se ha copiado la Base de datos",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I run in emulator and work perfectly, but in my devices dont work, the OS of emulator is 4.3 and OS of my devices is  4.0.4(rooted),4.0.4 and 4.3.

one line of DB is:

> 14    11107   Ovalo con mancuernas    11  Hombros 3   12  10  No hay datos    Utiliza
>   inicialmente las mancuernas con menor peso que encuentres en tu
>   gimnasio para que aprendas el movimiento y a dominar el peso.
>   Trabajarás la región anterior del
>   hombro.   img11107_1.png  img11107_2.png  img11107_3.png

**UPDATED:**

I put the solution in the next comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finanlly  i found de solution:

```
public void copyDB() {
    String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/MiBD";
    File f2 = new File(destPath);
    try {
        if (!f2.exists()) {
            //create a empty file
            InputStream iStream = getBaseContext().getAssets().open(
                    "datosejer");
            AdaptadorBD db = new AdaptadorBD(getApplicationContext());
            db.open();
            db.close();
            OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
            //open a file that was created and write data.
            db.open();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = iStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                oStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            iStream.close();
            oStream.close();
            db.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

now this work in device

Comment: What exactly was your solution? I am having same issue on but on emulator

Comment: I have changed the old copyDB() for this copyDB, maybe the solution is in: OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
            //open a file that was created and write data.
            db.open();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = iStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                oStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            iStream.close();
            oStream.close();
            db.close();

Comment: Hey thanks, yeah got that a while back i just wasn't opening the DB before copying.